# ISC DHCP Option 82 binary-to-ascii for host declaration

Tags: dhcp

If the relay agent encodes the option 82 as binary data (as is the case with Cisco and Brocade systems, at least), How can one perform this match:

---

```
host 10-24-24-9 {
    host-identifier option agent.circuit-id "<some circuit id>";
    fixed-address 10.24.24.9;
    server-name "192.168.0.12";
    filename "SomeCFG.cfg";
}
```

If I was doing it with a class statement, it would be done something like this:

---

```
class 10-24-24-9 {
    match if binary-to-ascii(10, 8, "", option agent.circuit-id) = "<some circuit id>";
}
```

.... some pool/range with single address allowing members of class 10-24-24-9

---

I don't want to do it with a class statement if I can help it as that prevents quick replacement of equipment until the lease expires (as address is already leased to previous equipment).  host {} with fixed-address makes no lease and therefore quick swap of equipment at the end of the circuit meets no resistance.

Any ideas?  (I've already tried harsh language)